# How to find shortest path from 2 point with going through a given road

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I have 4 point A B C D. Is There any way to find a shortest path from A to D and must going through B C.

Comment: In this case you have to compare only two ways - ABCD and ACBD. Are you aware about more general problem?

Comment: Look: [Floyd–Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)